# Show that the operator is compact.

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that if $\lambda_n \to 0$ so the operator

$$T: l^p \to l^p $$ , $$T (x_1, \cdots , x_n, \cdots)= (\lambda_1 x_1, \cdots, \lambda_n x_n, \cdots) $$

is compact to $1\leq p < \infty $.

I am tryng show that if $x_n$ is bounded so $T (x_n)$   is precompact.

Comment: Maybe you could see if $T$ is the limit of finite rank operators?

Comment: Neither of the above links have an answer to this.